# Use Apply to iterate through multiple response variables in a model and then input that model into stepwise model

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I am trying to use the apply function to create multiple linear models. My data has 32 linear models that will be created using 30 predictor variables. In this case, I am using the dummy data mtcars with only 5 predictors and 5 response variables as seen below (my actual data has about 30 of each). I want to use the `lapply ()` function to create the models and then feed each individual model seperately into a stepAIC function and then feed those models seperately into a stepVIF fucniton. In the end I want to output a list of all of the model results after the stepVIF funciton. Beginnings of code my code are below, I belive my major issue currenlty is the multiple na's that I have in my data. I only wish to remove na's from the predictor column when that model runs and not at the beginning from the entire data frame otherwise it removes some data that can be used. I can get this to work if I input one response variable at a time and copy paste the code over and over.

```
n=6
full.model <- lapply(1:n, function(p) lm((p)~., cars_data[, c(p, 7:11)]))   #Fit full lm model to the last 5 variables in mt cars and create a model for the first 6 variables in mtcars

step.model <- stepAIC(full.model, direction = "both", trace = FALSE) #Fit stepwise regression model

stepmod3 <- stepVIF(model = step.model, threshold = 10, verbose = TRUE)
```

I am currently running into a variable lengths differ error

Comment: Usually a stepwise procedure would give you the best-fitting model (subject to some stepwise inclusion/exclusion criterion) for a single response variable.  I'm not sure what you expect a stepwise model to do when you have multiple different response variables?  Or do you want `stepAIC()` to operate independently on each of the full models?

Comment: I want it to operate independently on each full linear model. Sorry, I should have phrased my initial question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
n=6
#Fit full lm model to the last 5 variables in mt cars and create a model for the first 6 variables in mtcars
full.model <- lapply(1:n, function(p) lm(reformulate(names(mtcars)[7:11], response=names(mtcars)[p]), mtcars))  

step.model <- lapply(full.model, function(x)MASS::stepAIC(x, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)) #Fit stepwise regression model

stepmod3 <- lapply(step.model, function(x)pedometrics::stepVIF(model = x, threshold = 10, verbose = TRUE))
```

---

### When missing data patterns are different.

When missing data patterns differ and you only want to delete the observations that have some missing data for that particular model, the easiest thing is to embed the data in the call.  For example, here's what it would look like with the `mtcars` data:

```r
library(dplyr)
n=6
#Fit full lm model to the last 5 variables in mt cars and create a model for the first 6 variables in mtcars
full.model <- lapply(1:n, function(p){ 
  args <- list(
    formula = reformulate(names(mtcars)[7:11], response=names(mtcars)[p]), 
    data= mtcars %>% select(p,7:11) %>% na.omit())
  do.call("lm", args)
})  

step.model <- lapply(full.model, function(x)MASS::stepAIC(x, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)) #Fit stepwise regression model

stepmod3 <- lapply(step.model, function(x)pedometrics::stepVIF(model = x, threshold = 10, verbose = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That works perfectly with mtcars. When applied to my data with multiple NA's in it, it gives me "Error in MASS::stepAIC(x, direction = "both", trace = FALSE) : number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?" I only want to take out na values in the column of the response variable when it being run through the model and the other columns. Do you have any way to do this?

Comment: @RW1201 I updated the answer to hopefully get you going in the right direction.